# Word for saying something brief with a low voice?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> “Look,” [...] said Anna, pointing forward.

At first thought of *mutter* but mutter implies dissatisfaction or irritation. Then I tried murmur, however, it's more a continous sound so it doesn't fit the sentence very well.

Is there a word for saying something brief with a low voice?

Comment: "Sotto voce", perhaps?

Comment: murmured could also work

Comment: "Hissed" has the necessary meaning but the tone is rather [Enid Blyton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enid_Blyton).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word ***mumble*** comes to mind.

> to utter words in a low confused indistinct manner
>   <sub>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mumble))</sub>

You could use it this way:

> "Look," *mumbled* Anna, pointing forward.

---

In comments from Erik, mumbling a single word may seem a bit unnatural. There is an idiom of saying something ***under one's breath***, which is used to indicate something being said very quietly. This idiom is difficult to use in your context, but Erik suggested ***breathed***, which I take to mean the word is mouthed and the sound of the word is pushed out with air from the lungs, but the vocal cords aren't really moving. (The second definition from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breathed) simply puts "voiceless".)

> "Look," *breathed* Anna, pointing forward.

Comment: In general, I think this would be a good answer. But there is a problem with it in the context of the OP's question, namely that "Look" is such a short utterance that it's hard to conceive of it being *mumbled:* the speaker has already finished the word before they could even start to *mumble*. *Whispered* or *mouthed* might be a better choice here.

Comment: @ErikKowal: I agree that a single word utterance would be unnatural to mumble for most people, but I would not discount it from happening. I wasn't sure if "low" was *quiet* or *deep*, but a mumble can be either one or both. Perhaps *under breath*?

Comment: I think that — with a tweak — you are onto something: "Look," **breathed** Anna, pointing forward.

Comment: I'd switch the order of your suggestions. It seems clear to me that users are upvoting *breathed*.

Answer (score 3):

To [whisper](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Whisper) : ( from TFD)

> - to utter with soft low sounds using the breath.

- "Look", whispered Anna, pointing forward.

Answer (score 1):

If the sound you're looking for is soft then *hush* could work. Perhaps her partner was chattering away and Anna wanted the person to be quiet. If Anna was tired, bored, or even feeling romantic, then *sigh* could equally fit. The word *look* could be said *sotto voce* in a single long breath, it would have an almost breathless quality to it, in this case, *sigh* would not be out of place.

> “Look,” [*hushed*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hush) Anna, pointing forward
>   “Look,” *[sighed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sigh)* Anna, pointing forward.

If instead you are looking for a more urgent tone, one that expresses a threat, tension or concern then either hiss or sibilate will do. They both express ways of speaking **in** a low voice.

> “Look,” [*hissed*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hiss) Anna, pointing forward
>   “Look,” [*sibilated*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sibilate) Anna, pointing forward

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing (or hearing) how *Look* can be said to *hush* someone. And in 5 decades I've never come across a person who *sibilates*...anything.

Comment: @CarSmack No, it's not the word, *look* in itself, but the manner and circumstances in which it is said that leads the reader to understand. As for *sibilated* it's not common, but it is used. Google books reports about 3,900 hits for [she sibilated](https://www.google.com/search?q=sibilated+synonyms&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=sibilated&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8184j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=she+sibilated)

Answer (score -3):

The word you are looking for is

> "Look," **murmured** Anna, pointing forward.

Comment: *murmured* is considered and rejected in the OP